# PHP writing a text file in the begin

Tags: php, text-files, fwrite

So we are making in the class a sort of log. There is a input box and a button. Everytime the button is pressed, PHP will write on the text file and prints the current log. Now the text appears on the bottom, and we need to have the text appear on the top. Now how would we do that?

We tried doing this with alot of my classmates but it all resulted in weird behavours. (Like text is printed more then once, etc)

Thanks alot!

EDIT: Sorry, here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>php script</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">  
    <input type="text" name="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <?php
        //Basic variables
        echo("<br/>");
        $myFile = "log.txt";
        $logfile = fopen($myFile,'r+');
        $theData = fread($logfile,filesize($myFile));

        //Cookie stuff so the username is rememberd.
        $username = $_COOKIE['gebruikerscookie'];;
        if(isset($_POST['username'])){
            $gebruiker = $_POST['username'];
            if($_COOKIE['gebruikerscookie'] == $gebruiker){
                $username = $_COOKIE['gebruikerscookie'];
                echo("Welcome back");
            }else{
                setcookie("gebruikerscookie", $gebruiker);
                $username = $_COOKIE['gebruikerscookie'];
                echo("Welcome dude!");
            }           
        }

        //Checks if theres something inside 
        if(isset($_POST['text'])){
            $message = "<br/>". $username ." : " . $_POST['text'];
            fwrite($logfile, $message ,strlen($message));
        }
        echo($theData);
    ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: My guess is you're using **a** or **a+** when opening the log with `fopen()`, you should use **r+** instead `'r+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `fopen` manual on modes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Try `'r+'    Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.`

Altough without any code this is hard to answer.

Comment: Your code looks ok, altough a `<br/>` in a text file doesnt make sense, unless you read it as HTML, otherwise make that `\n`. Furthermore, make sure you use `fclose()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$contentToWrite = "Put your log content here \n";
$contentToWrite .= file_get_contents('filename.log');
file_put_contents('filename.log', $file_data);
?>
```

This will add the previous content of your file after your cureent content and write on your file.

Please reply if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

you're just missing the

```
fclose();
```

I assume, since not closing a filehandle can cause a lot of strange errors like this.

So

```
$myFile = "log.txt";
$logfile = fopen($myFile,'r+');
........
//Checks if theres something inside 
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
   $message = "<br/>". $username ." : " . $_POST['text'];
   fwrite($logfile, $message ,strlen($message));
}
fclose($logfile); // close it outside the if-condition!
echo($theData);
```

should do the trick

Comment: Without closing it, it gave me 0 errors. But this is not about errors. I want my text file to be readed from bottom to top.

Comment: well it acted strange you said. and that IS AN ERROR. Not for the php script of course (it doesn't care much) but for you it is.

Answer (score -1):

```
$log = file('log.txt');
krsort($log);
foreach($log as $line) echo "$line<br>\n";
```